# auto_ptr and dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, boost

If I wish to use `dynamic_cast` with a `shared_ptr` I can use `dynamic_pointer_cast`. What do I use if I wish to cast an `auto_ptr`?  I'm assuming something that would look like below.

```
struct B : A { };
...
auto_ptr<A> base( ... );
auto_ptr<B> derive = dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(base);
```

I'm using boost for shared_ptr's

Comment: Wrong way around for the types A and B? No need to `dynamic_cast` from derived (`A`) to base (`B`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
auto_ptr<A> base( ... );
if(B* query = dynamic_cast<B>(base.get())) {
    // take ownership
    base.release();
    auto_ptr<B> derived(query);

    // use and/or pass derived around here
    // ...
} else {
    // no dice: leave base as owner
}
```

---

Since you're already doing that, then refactor it, slap it in the namespace of your choice and call it a day:

```
// Postcondition:
// where r is the returned pointer and p == from.get()
// EITHER r == 0 AND from.get() == p
// OR r.get() == dynamic_cast<To>(p) AND from == 0
template<typename To, typename From>
std::auto_ptr<To>
dynamic_pointer_cast(std::auto_ptr<From>& from)
{
    To* query = dynamic_cast<To>(from.get());
    return query ? from.release(), query : 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what I do now, I was just wondering if there was a standard way of doing it.

Comment: @edA-qa AFAICT there is no equivalent to the pointer casts for single-ownership pointers (i.e. `boost::scoped_ptr`, `std::auto_ptr `or `std::unique_ptr`) so I suggest rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

By the nature of `auto_ptr` (which you should never use. Or if you have to use it, never copy-construct or copy-assign it), copying is equivalent to moving. Therefore, there is no way to do a cast without transferring ownership, which causes the previous owner to lose ownership.

And what would happen if it returned an empty `auto_ptr` (meaning a failed `dynamic_cast`)? The original owner of the pointer has lost ownership, thanks to the cast. The new owner doesn't have the pointer, since the cast failed. So who would own it?

I'm sure you can partially specialize dynamic_pointer_cast for any pointer type you want however.

Also, `auto_ptr` is deprecated in C++0x; the standards committee isn't going to promote the use of deprecated functionality by making `dynamic_pointer_cast` work with it..

Comment: It may help to point out what you mean when you say 'never .... copy-assign' it (I assume as in you allow RVO 'move' assignment and perhaps parameter passing temps?)

Comment: Since I don't have a C++0x compiler I need to keep using `auto_ptr` for the time being. Ownership seems clear enough to me, if the cast fails then the object is simply deleted (you've assigned the ptr so the original one should lose ownership)

Answer (score 1):

It would go like this:

```
auto_ptr<Derived> pd(
    dynamic_cast<Derived*>( base.get() )? static_cast<Derived*>( base.release() ) : 0
    );
```

Then check whether an ownership transfer did occur.

If it didn't, you might `reset` the original `auto_ptr`, and throw an exception.

Since especially Microsoft's implementation of `auto_ptr` has been very shaky, and probably still is, it's important to *not* rely on the conversions guaranteed by the standard.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I really like the static cast after the dynamic check.